# Would restricting channels to a maximum make LN more decentralized?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, ln-opening-channels

Currently LN seems a bit centralized - few central, well funded nodes seem to route transactions and make profits. I was wondering if limiting the number of channels a node can open to a certain max number, would make the LN more decentralized, in a sense that big central nodes won’t be able to have hundreds of channels and the routing action will spread more evenly to the network. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you have any research results supporting your claims behind your question?

Comment: Absolutely not. Just wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Such rule would not change anything people could split their funds across several nodes similar to LNBIG.